# save method and delegate in detailTableViewController fail in Xcode

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2, delegation, detailview

I have a bug when I save information passed by a user in a detailTableViewController. Though when I force the debugger by pressing lecture, it carries on performing the coredata job, etc.

Here is my structure:
A detailTableViewController which presents staticcells that the user fills and then passed to the coredata.
It implements a delegate for the MainTableViewController to pop over it.

PhraseDetailTableViewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "Phrase.h"

 @class PhraseDetailTableViewController;

 @protocol AddPhraseTVCDelegate
   - (void) theSaveButtonOnThePhraseDetailWasTapped:(PhraseDetailTableViewController *) controller;
 @end


 @interface PhraseDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController

   @property (strong,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
   @property (nonatomic,weak) id <AddPhraseTVCDelegate> delegate;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phraseMotivationTextField;

   - (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

 @end
```

PhraseDetailTableViewController.m :

```
- (void)save:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"Telling the PhraseDetailTableViewController Delegate that Save was tapped on the PhraseDetailTableViewController");

  Phrase *phrase = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Phrase" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  phrase.motivation = phraseMotivationTextField.text;

  NSLog(@"la phrase est %@", phrase.motivation);

  [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];


  [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnThePhraseDetailWasTapped:self];
  NSLog(@"le message savebuttononethe.. a ete envoyé");
}
```

I delegated it to the main, here is the .H and .m

PhraseTableViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhraseDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h"
#import "Phrase.h"


@interface PhraseTableViewController : CoreDataTableViewController <AddPhraseTVCDelegate>

    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

PhraseTableViewController.m (extract where i pass the delegate and It receive the delegate method):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Phrase Segue"])
  {
     NSLog(@"Seeting PhraseTVC as a delegate of PhraseDetailTableViewController");

     PhraseDetailTableViewController *phraseDetailTableViewController= segue.destinationViewController;
     phraseDetailTableViewController.delegate=self;
     phraseDetailTableViewController.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
  }
}


- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePhraseDetailWasTapped:(PhraseDetailTableViewController *)controller
{
  [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  NSLog(@"c'est la methode en elle meme qui chie");
}
```

I think there is something to do with the subclassing of the Main/detail and its inherited delegate.  But i can't figure out what exactly implies this bug :s

CHeers,
Louis

Comment: [delegate performSelector:@sel(theSaveButtonOnThePhraseDetailWasTapped:) wihtObject:self... in PhraseDetailTableViewController.m have u tried it?

Comment: I receive an alert because it doesn't recognize the methode performSelector:withObject  :/